# Positioning div without 'position' attribute

Tags: css, position

I'm currently having a problem with the layout of elements. At the moment, I have the following schema:

[image]

My CSS code (simplified) is as follows:

```
#case1 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
 
#case2 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
 
#case3 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#case4 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#case5 {
  height: 190px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

The problem is this: There is area for case 5 on the left (below cases 1 and 2), is there any way to force it to go to the left (without using 'absolute' or 'relative' position) ?
Thank You.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't specify a `width` for the container, the block won't get pushed to the left again.

The `margin-top` becomes unnecessary, as it only adds up extra space. You could have a negative `margin-top` here, but it's not considered a clean solution.

Using different ways of sorting it should be possible to automate a grid, but as you specify `margin-top`'s per block, this should be fine.

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 225px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div>div {
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 50px;
}

#case1 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
 
#case2 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
 
#case3 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#case4 {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
 
#case5 {
  height: 190px;
  /* 
     Note how the margin-top is removed 
     To fill in the extra space, you can use a negative margin:
     margin-top: -5px;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="case1"></div>
  <div id="case2"></div>
  <div id="case3"></div>
  <div id="case4"></div>
  <div id="case5"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container > div {
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100px;
}
 #case1 {
     height: 20px;
     margin-top: 0;
}
 #case2 {
     height: 20px;
     margin-top: 0;
}
 #case3 {
     height: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px;
}
 #case4 {
     height: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px;
}
 #case5 {
     height: 190px;
     margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="case1">1</div>
<div id="case2">2</div>
<div id="case3">3</div>
<div id="case4">4</div>
<div id="case5">5</div>
</div>
```